# Cannot find class for bean with name

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-security

I am trying to run my web application on tomcat server and I am getting this error

> Related cause:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [com.mycom.myproj.utility.CustomPassword] for bean with
>   name 'customPassword' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mycom.myproj.utility.CustomPassword

and my configuration inside spring-security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="customPassword" class="com.mycom.myproj.utility.CustomPassword" />
```

and my project folder structure is

```
src
 --main
   --resources
     application.properties
   -- java


Webcontent
--WEB-INF
  spring-servelet.xml
  spring-security.xml
  --jsp
  --lib
```

I build this project using POM.xml

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Well, where is that class? A `ClassNotFoundException` indicates that a class is not on the classpath. Your build system isn't adding it.

Comment: do you a <mainClass> tag in your build tag?

Comment: Hi Sotirios class is there in target/myprojetc/WEB-INF/classes/... folder

Comment: Do you have the package names right?

Comment: yes, package name is correct as I am converting my exiting project into maven and it was working previously..is this something I need to put WEB-INF folder inside main? I have'nt change the WebContent folder structure

Comment: Micho, No there is no <mainClass> tag inside build tag

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not getting any error while building

Comment: Can you provide more details about what's in your project folder and subfolders? Do you have your Java packages and source files under src/main/java? Also, usually Maven expects Web content to be in src/main/webapp. And what's in WEB-INF/lib? You shouldn't need that if you're using Maven, it will create that when it builds your .war file.

Comment: check `ctrl+shift+T` type `CustomPassword` see what you getting?

Comment: Hi Rembo, I am not getting the CustomPassword. Does that mean that its not creating CustomPassword.class.Why this class is not getting created

Comment: Hi sdouglass , yes my source files are inside src/main/webapp but my WebContent folder is parellel to src as shown in directory structure in my question in WEB-INF/lib I have all the jar files